# Allowed memory size exhausted in both Joomla and Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, joomla, content-management-system, out-of-memory

I am trying to set up a website using Joomla and this is the error I get after accessing *localhost* (right after successful installation process):

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98304 bytes) in [...]\default_item.php on line 77
```

The same thing happens when using Drupal (before installation though). I have already tried changing `php.ini` (in location given by Joomla itself, so it's the right one. Interestingly, website on *localhost* does not work, while admin panel on *localhost/administrator* works, that's where I got the file location from) to look like this:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

I also tried putting `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` inside the script indicated in error and freeing some of my RAM, but still - no success.

I use WebServ, which uses Apache 2.2.6 and PHP 5.2.5.

What more can I do to overrun this problem?

**Edit:**

[Output of phpinfo(); for Joomla](http://pastebin.com/A85J2vFr)

Comment: start by looking at: "default_item.php on line 77"

Comment: @Dagon it happens on Drupal too. and it happens in different file. which would rather indicate something is wrong with my php settings than that both Joomla and Drupal scripts contain errors. right?

Comment: or both are so poorly coded they need more that 8mb of ram.

Comment: if you are still getting that error then you are not setting it inthe right place. I specifically states that it has 8 megs of memory to play with. You need to find correct ini file, change it, then restart apache.

Comment: @Dagon alright, but I won't rewrite code in such CMS like Joomla, it's not what I'm after. My question now is why it shows 8Mb limit even though I set `memory_limit` in php.ini as e.g. 512Mb.

Comment: is it the right php.ini file? `phpinfo();` see what that returns

Comment: @Dagon yes, it is for sure. C:/Windows/php.ini. And that's the one I'm altering. Both Joomla and Drupal use this file.

Comment: well something is incorrect, it cant be the right file and you get a compliant about an 8mb limit. did you restart the server after changing the limit?

Comment: @Dagon well, that's the file shown by `phpinfo();` and yes, I did restart the server every time I changed the values.

Comment: can you post the whole output of phpinfo(); in to the question.

Comment: @Dagon output for Joomla posted.

Comment: "memory_limit    8M      8M" , well if you are sure you are editing "C:\Windows\php.ini" and saving it, and restarting the server, im out of ideas

Comment: @Dagon nothing works. I am out ideas too. thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Did you change the existing setting or add one? If there is second declaration it will override the first.

Comment: @prodigitalson `memory_limit = 512M' is the only line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` overrides the default [PHP memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

By the way look out for never ending loops. It might be causing the error.